# Is "number of runs in a game in the first three innings" also a piece of stats?

Tags: baseball

At about 4′6″ into the video linked below, the announcer says "They're averaging about three runs a game in the first three innings."

The link starts at 4′1″.

Is "number of runs in a game in the first three innings" also a baseball stat? If yes, does the [following](https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/d/deverra01.shtml) stats about Rafael Devers include that info?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it’s a statistic - by definition. But no, it’s not a commonly used statistic, and wouldn’t appear on a BBRef player page. Baseball statistics like that are collected either by the sports department of the TV station, or by ESPN which is an entire sports TV station, or by a variety of other organizations; the [Society for American Baseball Research has a list of examples](https://sabr.org/how-to/statistical-databases-and-websites) as well as being one of those organizations itself.

In this case you probably could find it with a baseball reference advanced search for *team* stats - they didn’t mean Devers scores three runs on average in the first three innings (that would be not only a record but probably by a factor of four or five; I doubt anyone averages much more than one run a game)  but that the whole team does.

Comment: There's one specific (paid) site that I can't think of off the top of my head that telecasts commonly use for the weirder stats ("This is the first time since 1908 that three batters have had triples in a five game span" type of weirdness) - if someone remembers please feel free to add it to the answer or in your own, it's really bugging me :)

Comment: Such stats, presumably, sound more impressive than "The team tends to score early in the game."

Comment: @Joe [Elias Sports Bureau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_Sports_Bureau)?